# Converting Mobilenet segmentation model to tflite

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I beginner in Tensorflow so kindly forgive me for this simple question, but I am unable to find this answer any where. I am working on converting mobilenet Segmentation model  (http://download.tensorflow.org/models/deeplabv3_mnv2_pascal_trainval_2018_01_29.tar.gz) trained on Pascal dataset to Tensorflow-lite for mobile inference for more than a week but with no success. I am unable to define properly the input and output format for converter.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
img = tf.placeholder(name="Image", dtype=tf.float32, shape=(512,512,  3))
out = tf.placeholder(name="Output", dtype=tf.float32, shape=(512,512, 1))
localpb = 'frozen_inference_graph.pb'
tflite_file = 'retrained_graph_eyes1za.lite'
print("{} -> {}".format(localpb, tflite_file))
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(
localpb, img, out
)
tflite_model = converter.convert()


open(tflite_file,'wb').write(tflite_model)
```

But, it is throwing lots of error like eager excecution. Kindly tell me how should I write the code to convert above Mobilenet model to tflite.

Answer (score 1):

try this in command prompt or bash shell
You can use either of the following two ways

## for tensorflow installed from package manager

```
python -m tensorflow.python.tools.optimize_for_inference \
--input=/path/to/frozen_inference_graph.pb \
--output=/path/to/frozen_inference_graph_stripped.pb \
--frozen_graph=True \
--input_names="sub_7" \
--output_names="ResizeBilinear_3"
```

## build from source

```
bazel build tensorflow/python/tools:optimize_for_inference
bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/optimize_for_inference \
--input=/path/to/frozen_inference_graph.pb \
--output=/path/to/frozen_inference_graph_stripped.pb \
--frozen_graph=True \
--input_names="sub_7" \
--output_names="ResizeBilinear_3"
```

Hope it works!!

Comment: Thanks! But when I am running tflite model from tflite interpreter ( https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/g3doc/convert/python_api.md#tensorflow-lite-python-interpreter- ) it is giving me strange error.  "ValueError: Model provided has model identifier 'sub_', should be 'TFL3'". I am using tensorflow2.0

Comment: Why you chose specifically sub_7 in graph why not ImageTensor ?

Comment: I obtained from https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/segmentation/overview its starter model.

Comment: The ValueError model identifier thing means the model file is corrupt/incomplete, ie perhaps an indication that the conversion has failed in some way.